# How can I substring in a required format in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I have a string like this ,

```
NSString *strTest = @"Hii how are you doing @Ravi , how do u do @Kiran  where are you @Varun";
```

I want a substring from the above string which contains only the words which starts with '@'
i.e I need

```
NSString *strSubstring =  @"Ravi @kiran @varun";
```

Please help me out how could I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the string like below :-

```
NSArray * names = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

names array will now contain all the words in the string, now you can iterate over the array and check which of its index contains "@" character.

If you find "@", store that index value in some variable.

Comment: since i have many newline characters and white spaces , its taking next word also  ,,even after trimming my string using, NSString *strTrimmerContent = [strContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            
            strTrimmerContent = [strTrimmerContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];

Comment: I have removed those newlines  by doing replaceString @"\n" Bystrng@" ", and it is working fine,,thank u all for ur time

Answer (score 0):

you will love implementing this code. I have used a regular expression to perform the job. It will give you the matching strings.

```
NSString *strTest = @"Hii how are you doing @Ravi , how do u do @Kiran  where are you @Varun";
NSError *error;
//&[^;]*;
NSRegularExpression *exp =[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@[^ ]*" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *s1= [exp matchesInString:strTest options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTest length]) ];
    [s1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *result = obj;
        NSString *str = [strTest substringWithRange:result.range];
        NSLog(@"str %@",str);

    }];
```